# Global access for sqlDB on mobile device

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

I am creating a sqlite database for my mobile app. once the user has supplied the correct password the database is opened. Various screens of the application will need to read and write data from the db. is there a way I can make the connection global when I open it, so it can be accessed from any view?

the code I am useing to open the DB is

```
var sqlConnection:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();
                    sqlConnection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN,sqlOpenSuccess);

                    sqlConnection.open(DBFile, SQLMode.CREATE, false, 1024,null);
```

Thanks

JaChNo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate your SQLConnection information into a single class; and pass a reference to that custom connection class around to every view component that needs it.

You could also look into a framework such as RobotLegs or SWIZ that uses dependency injection to add your custom connection class into views as needed.

You could also look into using a Singleton, such as the Cairngorm ModelLocator to share your custom connection instance across multiple views.

Comment: Sorry to be so dumb, but I am brand new to adobe flex etc. do you mean do something similar to this? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good doc on creating a class.  If you don't understand what classes are, you're going to have an uphill battle trying to learn Flex.  Most of the documentation and other resources assumes past programming knowledge.  So devote some time to learn about programming concepts (Variables, Loops, conditionals), and encapsulation (Classes, Objects, functions).

Comment: Hi, I understand principals of classes etc, just brand new to flash builder, flex and mobile dev. The only languages I have developed in before are VB(I know, don't shudder too much) and php.